# How to only close one specific Dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

### Dialog 1

I have a form which is located in a Dialog.

[image]

### Dialog 2

When I then want to create a specific Action, I press the add Button and a second Dialog is opened.

[image]

When I then press "Save" on the second Dialog, it should save and go back to the first Dialog and I can then continue to edit that form.

### Problem

Sadly when I press "Save" on the second Dialog it saves the form, but then closes both dialogs.

### Code

Call for first Dialog:

```
openCreateDialog(): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ActionUpdateComponent, {
  width: '35%',
  hasBackdrop: true,
  disableClose: true,
  autoFocus: false,
  position: {
    top: '30px',
  },
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.loadPage();
});
```

Call for second Dialog:

```
openSpecActionCreateDialog(): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SpecActionUpdateComponent, {
  width: '35%',
  hasBackdrop: true,
  disableClose: true,
  autoFocus: false,
  position: {
    top: '30px',
  },
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.specAction = result;
  if(this.specAction.action && this.specAction.cataloglocalisation){
    this.specActions.push(this.specAction);
  }

});
```

The Buttons of Dialog 2:

```
<div> 
  <button mat-button type="button" id="cancel-save" class="btn btn-secondary" mat-dialog-close>
  <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>&nbsp;
  <span jhiTranslate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
  </button>

  <button mat-button type="submit" id="save-entity" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!editForm.valid" [mat-dialog-close]="specAction">
  <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>&nbsp;
  <span jhiTranslate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

### Edit

I just found out, that when I click the "Cancel" Button on Dialog 2 it perfectly just closes the dialog and goes back to the first Dialog.

Is there a difference between the tag `mat-dialog-close` and `[mat-dialog-close]="specAction"`?

Any Idea why this is happening? Is there a way to only close one dialog?

Comment: Try and change the second dialogRef to dialogRef2, also calling dialogRef2.afterClosed().

Comment: I tried this. Sadly still both dialogs get closed... I even put a `console.log()` to check whether the correct `dialogRef.afterClosed()` was called.

Comment: Passing a value to the `matDialogClose` (or `mat-dialog-close`) attribute essentially returns that same value to the caller which opened the dialog in the `afterClosed` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to write an answer to this question, even though the correct answer is in the comments of the questions. Credit goes to [Darren Street](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501128/darren-street).

Calling the different dialogs the same name wasn't the best idea and renaming them fixed the problem.

But then it still did not work...

Since I'm migrating the application there also was an older function, which would go to the previous state when called. Means, my dialog managed to get closed but then the "bad" function was called and the second dialog then got closed to.

Lesson learned: Check older code for small functions named weirdly.